# How to use roman numerals in ggplot's scale_x_date?

Tags: r, ggplot2, roman-numerals

I need to change format string "2016-06-29" to: 29.V.2016
I've try:

```
scale_x_date(date_labels = paste("%d", as.roman("%m"), "%Y", sep = "."))
```

but the only result I get is:
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
In addition: Warning message:
In .roman2numeric(x) : invalid roman numeral: %m

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via the `labels` argument of `scale_x_date`. In my code below I make use of a custom function to convert dates to your desired format with roman literals for the month:

```r
library(ggplot2)

date_roman <- function(x, sep = ".") {
  paste(format(x, "%Y"), as.roman(as.numeric(format(x, "%m"))), format(x, "%d"), sep = sep)
}  

x <- as.Date("2016-06-29")
date_roman(x)
#> [1] "2016.VI.29"

ggplot(subset(economics, as.numeric(format(date, "%Y")) == 2000), aes(date, psavert)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_roman)
```

[image]